# My Kotlin fat JAR is failing to load a dependency correctly but only when it's run under FreeBSD, what can cause this?

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, jar, freebsd

This is a really weird one. I have a Kotlin web service that was originally written as a hybrid app of both Kotlin and Java but I've recently migrated to pure Kotlin (although many of its libraries are still in Java). The framework I'm using is sparkjava and I'm using Maven to manage dependencies and packaging. The service in the past was built with manually included dependencies as JAR files and was built using an IntelliJ configuration, this was horribly messy and difficult to reproduce so I moved all the dependencies into Maven and set up a process for this. This is where things get weird:

I included this plugin in my pom.xml to manage the creation of the fat JAR which looks like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>

            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>unifessd.MainKt</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I run this confuration however, I get a JAR that won't execute. I didn't think this was a major problem, as running the "package" lifecycle in Maven *does* produce an executable JAR. This resultant JAR will happily run on my development machine (macOS Big Sur) and will pass all my external testing scripts. However, when I deploy the very same JAR to my production environment which is a FreeBSD server on AWS, it will start up correctly but whenever I make a request I get the following error:

> [qtp248514407-20] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel -
> //<redacted.com>/moderation/users/administrators
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> de.mkammerer.argon2.jna.Argon2Library
> at de.mkammerer.argon2.BaseArgon2.hashBytes(BaseArgon2.java:267)
> at de.mkammerer.argon2.BaseArgon2.hashBytes(BaseArgon2.java:259)
> at de.mkammerer.argon2.BaseArgon2.hash(BaseArgon2.java:66)
> at de.mkammerer.argon2.BaseArgon2.hash(BaseArgon2.java:49)
> at [...]

I've truncated the stack trace to keep things concise but all it's doing before that is opening the appropriate DAO and hashing the password attempt. The offending class is of course de.mkammerer.argon2, which is a dependency I use to hash passwords using the argon2 algorithm. This has me really stumped for the following reasons:

- When this dependency was linked in manually using a JAR in IntelliJ, it worked absolutely fine in production.
- Even though the class fails to load in production, it works fine locally despite the packages being identical.
- macOS and FreeBSD aren't exactly a million miles apart in terms of how they're put together, so why are they behaving so differently?

A few other points in my efforts to debug this:

- I've tried linking in my argon2 library in the old way, and it's still failing in the same fashion.
- IntelliJ isn't recognising the main class of my Kotlin app any more if I try and create an artifact without Maven. This is really weird, I can set up a Kotlin build and run configuration just fine by specifying `unifessd.MainKt` as my main class, but when it comes to building an artifact it's simply not having it. It doesn't appear in the artifact creation dialogue and when I specify it as my `Main-Class` in MANIFEST.MF, IntelliJ tells me it's an invalid main class. What on Earth is going on here? It'll run just fine when I tell Maven that's my main class and package it in a JAR, even in the faulty production environment.

Comment: It seems like a JNA/JNI (native code) issue as the missing class seems to be de.mkammerer.argon2.*jna*.Argon2Library. Are you sure argon2 supports FreeBSD?

Comment: Most likely `de.mkammerer.argon2.jna.Argon2Library` has a static block that loads the JNI library via `System.loadLibrary(..)` when the class is loaded. If the JNI loading fails (because there is no compatible JNI library for BSD and the current CPU architecture) the class loading also fails and you end up with that error.

Comment: You know what, I think this is the error. I was going to say "it worked fine before I started screwing with the build system" but I'm not sure that part of the code ever actually got tested before I moved everything over to Maven. I'll test it later, but I suppose my options are to either figure out a different way of doing argon2 hashing or migrate to a different server OS that will support it. Cheers for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Robert and dan1st were correct, the problem was that my argon2 library had a dependency on JNA and native code that was incompatible with FreeBSD. I tested the JAR on an Ubuntu server to confirm that this was the case and the program ran correctly.